# How to Change the Name of a Pygame window?

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to change the name of a pygame window from "Pygame Window" to "test caption".
I have tried:

```
pygame.display.set_caption('test caption')
```

But I don't think it is the right script.

Comment: That should work; it is the correct method to change the window's caption. Have you created a window and made sure this line is run?

Comment: @Ted Klein Bergman Ah, I put it before I created the window. It works now. Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Refer to http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.set_caption:

```
set_caption(title, icontitle=None) -> None
```

> If the display has a window title, this function will change the name
>   on the window. Some systems support an alternate shorter title to be
>   used for minimized displays.

Your usage was correct, so there must be another issue.  Either your window is initialized incorrectly, or it isn't even initialized at all.  Contributing your code would be helpful.

Answer (score 15):

Call it after `init()`.

```
pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_caption('test caption')
```

Answer (score 0):

Just call the set_caption() function again.

```py
pygame.display.set_caption('original caption')

while myGameRunning:
    pygame.display.set_caption('new caption')
```

Answer (score 0):

[`pygame.display.set_caption()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.set_caption):

> If the display has a window title, this function will change the name on the window. [...]

However, PyGame is based on [SDL](https://www.libsdl.org/) and the behavior is system-dependent. Call `set_caption()` after initializing the display window with  [`pygame.display.set_mode()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.set_mode). In addition, the events may need to be handled after changing the window title. See [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump):

> internally process pygame event handlers. [...] This ensures your program can internally interact with the rest of the operating system.

```py
window = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption('window caption')
pygame.event.pump()
```

In a common application, you have an application loop and an event loop. This makes the additional call to `pygame.event.pump()` superfluous, since the events are continuously handled in the application loop:

```py
window = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption('window caption')

# [...]

run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
    
    # [...]
```