# How do I prevent the default window title to show when opening window in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

Every time I open a pygame window with pygame.display.set_mode, it shows the default pygame icon and title on the window.

I use pygame.display.set_caption() to change it, but for 2 seconds when opening the window it shows the default title. I want to make a quality game, but think that this is not too good for it.

Is there a way to edit the pygame package file to show my game's title instead of the default one?

[Opening the window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fb2Zb.png)

[After opening the window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbcCO.png)

Comment: Maybe you could share some of your code? Where do you set the caption? Perhaps that code is executed too late? According to this answer you should set it directly after initializing the window https://stackoverflow.com/a/46147147/9578273

Comment: I set it right after initializing the window, but it still doesn't work...

Comment: never mind, after making the display title change in the first line of the source code, I managed to fix it.

Comment: In that case please add an answer and mark it as the solution. In your answer detail how to solve the problem, so others in the future who have the same question can find the solution.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

ALl you have to do is make sure the command to change the window icon and title is one of the first commands issued in the source pygame files.